# Why do i get a "BadGateway" Error When Running the Excel Online "Run Script" Action in PowerAutomate?

Tags: power-automate, bad-gateway, office-scripts

I have recently being using the new Office Scripts function on Excel Online, and when i have tried to connect this with flow and try to run the script, it results in a BadGateway Error, after it retries twice

[BadGateway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YclR.png)

Can anyone help with this?

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 502,
    "message": "BadGateway",
    "innerError": {
      "message": "We were unable to run the script. Please try again.
...
```

Many thanks

Comment: Not sure why this was closed—the BadGateway error in this case appears to be a service issue. As in the error message, the best approach here is to simply run the flow again.